# parsing XML using java script or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

Can someone please help me with parsing below XML in javascript or JQuery?
I am not able to parse or not able to find relevant examples.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <DataSet xmlns="http://abcd.com/WebServices/">
- <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
- <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
- <xs:complexType>
- <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
- <xs:element name="ResultSet">
- <xs:complexType>
- <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="mdescnum1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /> 
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
- <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
- <NewDataSet xmlns="">
- <ResultSet diffgr:id="ResultSet1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
  <mdescnum1>aaaaaaaa</mdescnum1> 
  </ResultSet>
- <ResultSet diffgr:id="ResultSet2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
  <mdescnum1>bbbbbb</mdescnum1> 
  </ResultSet>
  </NewDataSet>
  </diffgr:diffgram>
  </DataSet>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one help you out.

```
var xml = $.parseXML(yourfile.xml),
  $xml = $( xml ),
  $test = $xml.find('test');

console.log($test.text());
```

use your tag name on behalf of 'test'.